# Replace product image by a placeholder based on user roles in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, user-roles

In WooCommerce I am using user roles to define what each user role can see. If the user is "customer" or "administrator", he is able to see the product image, otherwise he see WooCommerce default placeholder image.

For that I use the code below:

```
function woocommerce_product_get_image_id_callback( $value ) {
    global $current_user;

    if ( in_array( 'customer', (array) $current_user->roles )|| in_array( 'administrator', (array) $current_user->roles )) {
        return $value;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_image_id', 'woocommerce_product_get_image_id_callback', 10, 1 );
```

It works for simple products, **but not for variable products**: 
On variable products when no variation has been selected a placeholder is displayed, but when user choose any variation an image appears instead.

Can anyone help to fix this please? Maybe disable to choose product variations in the if?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:** The following replacement code will handle all product types (even variable products with their variations):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_image_id', 'woocommerce_product_get_image_id_callback', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_image_id', 'woocommerce_product_get_image_id_callback', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_product_get_image_id_callback( $image_id, $product ) {
    if ( ! ( current_user_can('customer') || current_user_can('administrator') ) ) {
        $image_id = '';
    }
    return $image_id;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Super, it works perfect. But I had to invert $image_id = ' '; and return $image_id;