# Change product image in product carousel wcps

Tags: image, woocommerce, carousel, product, user-roles

If the user is a customer or an admin I show the product image, otherwise I show the default woocommerce placeholder image using *"[Replace product image by a placeholder based on user roles in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569578/replace-product-image-by-a-placeholder-based-on-user-roles-in-woocommerce/55570068#55570068)"* answer code to one of my previous questions.

Now I would like to use the woocommerce product slider plugin (WCPS) on the home page but there the slider still shows the real product image. Can anyone help with this please?